# How to link against libc6-dbg instead of just libc6

Tags: qt, qmake, debug-symbols, libc

I've a program, compiled in debug mode. Yet when I do ldd:

```
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00821000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0083c000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00921000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x009ac000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x152fa000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x0094d000)
...
```

I don't see any debug symbols here...

My program crashed, and I have that output in gdb bt:

```
#0  0x00007f2f95ca7030 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007f3013edd801 in ?? ()
#2  0x0002965300014c4c in ?? ()
#3  0x00007f305e3006c0 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007f3000000084 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007f3000000002 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007f307a57aec0 in ?? ()
#7  0x000000000494c740 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007f3092e93720 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#9  0x0000000000000030 in ?? ()
#10 0x000000000b85de60 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007f305f913000 in ?? ()
#12 0x00007f3095cbe750 in ?? ()
#13 0x00007f3089eb2390 in ?? ()
#14 0x00007f3095cc4a88 in ?? ()
#15 0x00007f30956b4d78 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtScript.so.4
#16 0x00007f3095cc3800 in ?? ()
#17 0x00007f3089eb2000 in ?? ()
#18 0x00007f3088c41230 in ?? ()
#19 0x00007f30956b4d78 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtScript.so.4
#20 0x0000000004c35488 in ?? ()
#21 0x00007f3089eb2060 in ?? ()
#22 0x00007f3095cbe738 in ?? ()
#23 0x00007f30952c83a1 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtScript.so.4
#24 0x00007f309535f567 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtScript.so.4
#25 0x00007f30953349a2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtScript.so.4
#26 0x00007f30954176ce in QScriptValue::call(QScriptValue const&, QList<QScriptValue> const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtScript.so.4
... (Readable backtrace from my code)
```

So my question is, how do I link to the debug version of libc6? If I know what to pass to the compiler, I can then put that in the qmake file so it would be compiled that way.

I've installed libc6-dbg, too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't see any debug symbols here...

It's not clear how you obtained that stack trace. Chances are you didn't invoke GDB correctly.

> How to link against libc6-dbg instead of just libc6

You do no such thing. `libc6-dbg` package supplies [separate debug files](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html). You don't link against them -- GDB knows how to load them automagically.

Comment: For the record, the rest of the backtrace below *was* readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply different configurations through the `CONFIG` macro in the qmake file:

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    LIBS += -llibc6-dbg
} else {
    LIBS += -llibc6
}
```

If you're trying to understand the syntax: It tells qmake to check for the options `debug` and `release` in the `CONFIG` variable, and if it finds `debug`, execute the first path, otherwise the second one.

If you're having any kind of troubles, [this forum thread](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/3972) might help you.

Comment: can't find -llibc6-dbg, the only thing it can find is -lc

Comment: I assumed it would be in the same folder as libc6. If it is in a different folder, you will have to add `-Lpath/to/the/lib` to your `LIBS` variable.

Comment: The libc6-dbg package provides /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so, but linking against that library will cause immediate crash -- it's not for linking against, and does not contain executable code, only the debug info.